# Pretty permalinks to work for lighttpd webserver?

Tags: permalinks, blog

Does anyone know how to set up pretty permalinks for lighttpd web server? I've search on the web, but I didn't find anything reliable.

Until now I only tried [this](http://eraldmariano.com/raspberry-pi-lighttpd-and-wordpress-pretty-permalink/) which didn't work. Is this method good or should I do something special in my wordpress conf after doing the changes?

**Edit:**

I've also used this method [here](http://virtual.berrydejager.com/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-permalinks-when-using-lighttpd/) but unfortunately I got 404 error when accessing my wordpress page.

Comment: Frankly, only this: http://eraldmariano.com/raspberry-pi-lighttpd-and-wordpress-pretty-permalink/

Comment: I added the link to [ask] for a reason :/ Please read that and then file an [edit] and put everything we need to know _in_ the question instead of linking to it. Thanks.